# Cómo enviar correo directamente desde android

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una app para la gestión de incidencias de una empresa.

En una de las actividades, se registra una incidencia y hay un botón enviar, el cual debe mandar el correo. Esto quiero que sea ajeno al usuario.

¿Que método debería utilizar? Desde Android sé cómo enviar un email abriendo la aplicación de gmail u otro gestor de correos, pero existe una posibilidad de enviarla directamente sin pasar por ahí?.

Si conocéis otra manera estaré encantado de leerla.

Comment: Yo lo haria mediante petición ajax, hacia un servidor donde mande el email o lo guarde directamente al sistema de incidencias

Comment: peticion ajax? me podrias poner alguna ejemplo si no es mucha molestia?

Comment: Mira aquí hay un pequeño ejemplo por parte de cliente Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768658/ajax-call-in-java-client-application

Comment: Un petición ajax en android es una petición HTTP.
Lo que tienes que hacer es configurar un servidor smtp para el correo, por ejemplo el de Gmail https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=es, aquí un ejemplo http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-send-e-mail-directly-from-android-application/

Comment: @Sergiocv hola, Deseas enviar un email sin abrir el Cliente de google?

Comment: @StefanNolde para marcarla como duplicado , se toma en cuenta la fecha de la pregunta ? es decir esta pregunta al parecer se realizo antes que la otra.

Comment: Dejame ver, @Dev.Joel - si, se debería (aun que también podría depender de la calidad de la pregunta. Parece que me confundi con las fechas

Comment: Al revés no funciona el cierre, porque la otra pregunta contiene un detalle más, @Dev.Joel

Comment: @Dev.Joel No es necesario tomar la fecha. Es importante, sí, pero no necesario... Buen criterio ante todo. [¿Qué tipo de pregunta debería marcarse como duplicada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/982/127)

Comment: Además, no se puede marcar como duplicada de otra pregunta que no ha tenido solución.

Comment: Esto que deseas lo pude realizar hace tiempo pero con IOS aunque debería ser lo mismo para android utilizando la API de MailChimp.

Answer (score 8):

Se que no es lo que deseas, pero si quieres enviar un mail a través de la app de gmail es tan sencillo como hacer un intent tal que así:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","correo@gmail.com", null));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Android APP - ");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,  getActivity().getString(R.string.enviar_mail)));
```

En tu caso, que buscas la mínima interacción del usuario y que la gestión se haga de manera cuasi automática, podrías usar la librería [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Tienes un ejemplo básico (tanto de lectura como de envío) en [mi repositorio](https://github.com/helicida/Example_ClienteMail/tree/master/src).

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! probaré esto ultimo!

Answer (score 5):

Si quieres enviar un correo directamente en Android, puedes usar [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android)

en tu `build.gradle` del proyecto necesitas agregar el repositorio de maven:

```
repositories { 
     jcenter()
     maven {
         url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
     }
 }
```

y en tus dependencias del build tienes que agregar a las dependencias:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
 }
```

Te dejo la clase `MailJob` como ejemplo.

```
/**
 * Created by snolde on 06-04-2017.
 */

public class MailJob extends AsyncTask<MailJob.Mail,Void,Void>{
    private final String user;
    private final String pass;

    public MailJob(String user, String pass) {
        super();
        this.user=user;
        this.pass=pass;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Mail... mails) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
                    }
                });
        for (Mail mail:mails) {

            try {

                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.from));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(mail.to));
                message.setSubject(mail.subject);
                message.setText(mail.content);

                Transport.send(message);

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                Log.d("MailJob", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static class Mail{
        private final String subject;
        private final String content;
        private final String from;
        private final String to;

        public Mail(String from, String to, String subject, String content){
            this.subject=subject;
            this.content=content;
            this.from=from;
            this.to=to;
        }
    }
}
```

Para enviar correos llamas al siguiente código (con los datos que quieres enviar desde tu resultado):

```
new MailJob(user, passwd).execute(
              new MailJob.Mail("from@gmail.com", "to@otromail.com", "subjeto", "contenido")
            );
```

Comment: Enlace actualizado a github.io

Comment: el gradle no sincroniza marca error... intenté con tu clase pero marca demasiados errores que android no me deja corregir, iniciando por Session no la reconoce, javax.mail tampoco ni MimeMessage estoy usando android studio 3.0

Answer (score 3):

Esta sería una opción usando un Intent "chooser", lo que realiza es abrir automáticamente una pantalla de dialogo con todas las aplicaciones instaladas en tu dispositivo que pueden realizar el envío de un email:

```
  String[] TO = {""}; //Direcciones email  a enviar.
  String[] CC = {""}; //Direcciones email con copia.

  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Tu Asunto...");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "tuemail@email.com"); // * configurar email aquí!

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email."));        
     Log.i("EMAIL", "Enviando email...");
  }
  catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "NO existe ningún cliente de email instalado!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Tu puedes realizar la selección del cliente para envío del email!.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenos dias, gracias por la respuesta. 
La verdad es que lo que necesito es que el usuario no vea que esta enviando un email, sino que para el sea un formulario y lo reciba el destinatario en forma de mail.

Comment: ok actualizaré mi respuesta.