# Enviar correo electrónico desde aplicación android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

el problema que tengo es que deseo asignar solo aplicaciones que correo electrónico al pulsar dicho envió. Aclaro el envio funciona solo que al momento de mostrar las aplicaciones las muestra todas, hasta el traductor de google y como mencione quiero solo app de correos.

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"algo@gmail.com" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "un correo");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "prueba");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Seleccionar aplicación."));
```

en la linea `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Seleccionar aplicación."));`
 esta es la encargada de mostrar las app. saludos !

Comment: que es dar bien ? jaja te refieres a marcar como buena si lo hago ! jaja

Answer (score 2):

Cambia el `MIME` type a `message/rfc822`, usa `{tu intent}.setType("message/rfc822")`

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"algo@gmail.com" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "un correo");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "prueba");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Seleccionar aplicación."));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si la verdad limito mucho mas las app, pero aun asi me aparece apps como OneNotas o Dropbox

Comment: Esos tambien usan el mismo protocolo de los correos, no podrás filtrar más. Si mi respuesta te ayudo, marcala como correcta por favor

Comment: Si asi parece, no se podra filtrar mas, gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Esta sería una opción usando un Intent "chooser", lo que realiza es abrir automáticamente una pantalla de dialogo con todas las aplicaciones instaladas en tu dispositivo que pueden realizar el envío de un email, se agrega validación por si no se tiene instalado un programa para manipular este tipo de información:

```
  String[] TO = {""}; //Direcciones email  a enviar.
  String[] CC = {""}; //Direcciones email con copia.

  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Tu Asunto...");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "tuemail@email.com"); // * configurar email aquí!

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email."));        
     Log.i("EMAIL", "Enviando email...");
  }
  catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "NO existe ningún cliente de email instalado!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Tu puedes realizar la selección del cliente para envío del email!.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Cómo enviar correo directamente desde android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11542/enviar-correo-desde-android-opciones)

Answer (score -1):

He encontrado la solución para que esto que como he pedido. Muestra solo los clientes de correo electrónico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la forma es esta :

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","tucorreo@gmail.com", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "texto aqui");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "*texto aqui*)");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "enviar correo ..."));
```