# Enviar correo electronico sin interacción con el usuario

Tags: java, android, email

Deseo enviar un **email** al realizar una acción determinada, es decir después de ejecutar un `Asyntask`, pero **sin que el usuario tiene que eligir una aplicación** para enviar correos. He buscado información de esto pero nada útil hasta el momento. ¿ alguien tiene algún método para realizar esto?

**Tengo el siguiente codigo**

```
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","algo@gmail.com", null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "texto");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "*Ayudanos mejorar enviando, tu sugerencia o reportando un error*)");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar comentarios sobre algo"));
```

¿existe alguna forma de ejecutar esto sin interacción? Si es que no hay otro metodo

Answer (score 2):

Si deseas realizarlo "automaticamente" al terminar de realiza un Asynctask, simplemente llama el envío en el método `onPostExecute()`:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                    "mailto","algo@gmail.com", null));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "texto");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "*Ayudanos mejorar enviando, tu sugerencia o reportando un error*)");
            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar comentarios sobre algo"));

     }
```

Muy importante, si tienes tu `Asynctask` en otra clase, en el constructor del `Asynctask` debes recibir el contexto;

```
   public MyAsyncTask (Context context){
         mContext = context;
    }
```

Esto para que al realizar el Intent para el envio de correo funcione sin problema:

```
  mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar comentarios sobre algo"));
```

---

Otro método es realizar una interfaz que se llame al terminar tu `Asynctask`, método `onPostExecute()`, esto si tu método para envio de e-mail se encuentra en otra clase.

Comment: Lo malo es que no deseo que se abra la interfaz ...

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres enviar un correo directamente en Android, puedes usar [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android):

en tu `build.gradle` del proyecto necesitas agregar el repositorio de maven:

```
repositories { 
     jcenter()
     maven {
         url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
     }
 }
```

y en tus dependencias del build tienes que agregar a las dependencias:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
 }
```

Un `AsyncTask` con un ejemplo [encuentras aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11542/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-correo-directamente-desde-android/61264#61264).

La respuesta contiene una clase `MailJob` para enviar correo directamente sin eligir otra aplicación.

En `onPostExecute()` de tu **otro** `AsyncTask` llamas al siguiente código (con los datos que quieres enviar desde tu resultado):

```
new MailJob(user, passwd).execute(
              new MailJob.Mail("from@gmail.com", "to@otromail.com", "subjeto", "contenido")
            );
```