# Error con el envio de email con android

Tags: java, android, email

Buenas quiero enviar mensajes de email pero me da un error y no se porque, la contraseña esta bien puesta

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public void enviarCorreos(){

    final String correoEnvio = "playbetwin2016@gmail.com";

    final String contraseña= ""; //en la aplicación esta puesta
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.googlemail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); // required for Gmail


    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(correoEnvio, contraseña);
            }
        });

        if (session!= null){
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correoEnvio));
            message.setSubject("holaaa");
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("sergio.alcantara.1992@gmail.com"));
            message.setContent("holaaa","text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(message);

        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Y me da el siguiente error

```
05-28 16:42:06.875 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente.Principal.enviarCorreos(Principal.java:422)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente.Principal.consePremios(Principal.java:388)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-28 16:42:06.895 1992-1992/com.example.sergio.playbetwincliente W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Uso las libreia javax.mail, additionnal y activation

Y con el permiso de internet activado ya que lo uso para otra parte del proyecto

Comment: Que biblioteca estas usando para mail? Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11542/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-correo-directamente-desde-android/61264#61264) para código de referencia que comprobadamente funciona con gmail.

Comment: la guia que vi usaba 3, mail, additionnal  y activation

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta referenciado en mi comentario, java.net fue migrado a github.io. Las bibliotecas de javaee no funcionan desde la caja con android, pero alla se encuentra una adaptación que funciona maravilloso. Se necesitad dos paquetes de maven no más.

Comment: JavaX.mail es la que uso de mail

Comment: JavaX.mail no te va resultar con Android. Revisa la biblioteca que sale en el enlace que te compartí.

Comment: ok, mañana quiero problarlo. Espero que funcione que dentro de nada tengo que entregar el proyecto T-T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya Muchas gracias a https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/26822/stefan-nolde, mire el enlace y era que no tenia

```
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
```

Con esa simple linea se soluciono mi problema, pero como vi creabas una clase para el envió me convenció mas esa idea, asi que la probé y también funciona muy bien. Muchas gracias

Dejo el enlace

[Cómo enviar correo directamente desde android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11542/c%C3%B3mo-enviar-correo-directamente-desde-android/61264#61264)